# How to change the color of contour values?

Tags: plotting

I have contour plot and I want to change the font color of the contour values. 
meanwhile, changing the background to white. 
can anybody help?
this is what I've found. but it only gives 9 contours, I need arbitrary numbers as well.

```
ContourLabels -> (Text[
Style[#3, 
 Switch[#3, 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3, White, 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6, White, 
  0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9, White]], {#2, #2}, Background -> Black] &)
```

Comment: It is better if you start with a specific example so that the solutions we provide can be consistent. For starters, are you looking at 2D or 3D contourplot ?

Comment: this is the example i can provide.

Comment: ContourPlot[Sqrt[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "IslandColors", 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[ "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(i\)]\)(keV)", 
    FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(e\)]\)(keV)", FontSize -> 14, 
    FontFamily -> "Times"]},

Comment: ContourLabels -> (Text[
     Style[#3, 
      Switch[#3, 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3, White, 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6, White, 
       0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9, White]], {#2, #2}, Background -> Black] &), 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[#3, {#2, #2}, Background -> Black] &), 
 LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, Bold], (FontSize -> 16), 
   FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     Style["\[Rho]R(g.\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(-2\)]\))", 
      FontSize -> 12]], {After, Center}]]

Comment: I have never seen a Switch inside Style before. What is the intention of this ? Is this a documented example ?

Comment: i just wanted to change the contours font color. i found "Switch" on this website. it seems to work, bu not completely.

Comment: Do you want the contour labels to have different colors ? If so on what basis do you want to fix the color ?

Comment: yes, the default color is black. i want to change it into white.

Answer (score 1):

How about this example then?

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "IslandColors", 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[Style[Framed[#3], 20, White], {#1, #2}, 
     Background -> Black] &)]
```

The Background is Black, Labels are in White, and the Label Font Size is set to 20.

Comment: Thank you very much. i exactly wanted this. the code i had made it too difficult. thank you very much indeed.